# I would like to read the WiFi rssi values between 2 android phones

Tags: android, android-wifi, rssi

I have two android phones and can successfully measure each of their respective RSSI measurements to connected Wireless Access Points. I would like to be able to read the RSSI between the two phones themselves, with a view to estimate the distance between each device.

Answer (score 0):

One way I see in order to calculate the RSSI between each other is the following logic:

- Make the one Android device (lets say device_1) to be the Access Point using WiFi tethering
- Let the other Android device (lets say device_2) to measure the RSSI from the device_1. This is possible now because due to the wifi tethering of device_1 now the device_2 will be able to see the device_1 in its wifi scan results and even if you want connect to that.
- Now make the opposite one. Make the device_2 to make use of WiFi tethering and then let device 1 to calculate the RSSI from device_2.

In order to catch any possible questions on that, you have to do it both ways, meaning that both devices must use the WiFi tethering and get 2 measurements. This is for two reasons. Firstly, multiple devices have defferent transmit powers so, you will read different rssi values (even if the transmitted power is the same then again due to different scatterring environment the rssi values would differ). Secondly, you will be more accurate if you obtain 2 values and even better if you repeat this methodology more than one time and make an average of them, but keep in mind that you cannot divide dBm values. You can take a look in my answer on the following post for that

[WiFi readings unstable in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294860/wifi-readings-unstable-in-android/27013491#27013491)